# Mint 14 Floppy error

Tags: linux-mint, floppy

```
Error reported = Error mounting system managed device /dev/fd0. Command line ... /media/flopp0 exited with non-zero . /dev/fd0 is not a valid block device.
```

I've got a physical floppy drive, working (well it stops boot ups if a floppy is inserted) and occasionally I need to use it, so how do I rectify the error?

---

Reading elsewhere on the web, it appears to be a module as the exact message is:-
 ''Error mounting system-managed device /dev/fd0: Command-line `mount "/media/floppy0"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/fd0 is not a valid block device''

Comment: Is floppy module loaded? `# lsmod  | grep floppy`

Comment: The output from the above command is:-   floppy  55444  0